# Как добавить outerHTML в куки?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Как добавить HTML код определенных элементов в куки?Точнее есть генератор который при нажатии генерирует div элемент с рандомным цветом и в рандомный месте. Надо реализовать кнопку "Сохранить", эта кнопка должна сохранять количество,цвет и местоположение всех div элементов **в куки**(это обязательно). Пробовал сохранить HTML код элементов,но сохраняется только первые 20 символов. Как быть?
`var

```
 btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var divMove = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
    divList = [],
    osX = 0,
    osY = 0,
    ae;

getRandom = (min, max) => {
  return Math.round(Math.random() *(max - min) + min);
};

function setCookie(elem){
  document.cookie = `name=${elem}`;
}

btn.addEventListener('click',() => {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  divMove = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.setAttribute('data-random','true');
  div.style.width = getRandom(10,window.innerWidth/2) + 'px';
  div.style.height = getRandom(10,window.innerHeight/2) + 'px';
  div.style.top = getRandom(0,window.innerHeight) + 'px';
  div.style.left = getRandom(0,window.innerWidth) + 'px';
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + getRandom(0,255) + ',' + getRandom(0,255) + ',' + getRandom(0,255) + ')';
  divList.push(div.outerHTML);
  setCookie(divList);
  drag(div);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
});

function drag(div){
  var mUp = () => {
    ae = null;
  };

  var mMove = (e) => {
    if(ae){
      ae.style.top = (e.clientY - osY) + 'px';
      ae.style.left = (e.clientX - osX) + 'px';
    }
  };
  div.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    ae = e.target;
    osX = e.offsetX;
    osY = e.offsetY;
  });

  div.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      mUp();
  });
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      mMove(e);
    });
}`
```

Comment: Сохранять в куки HTML плохая идея. Я бы сохранял этот HTML где-то на сервере в файле, а потом просто доставал его.

Comment: Приведите код, которым вы сохраняете/читаете куки.

Comment: Как вариант лучше использовать не куки, а `localStorage`, и записать в него массив объектов вида `[{coordX:123, coordY:123, color:red},...]`

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно экранировать знак ";" *(которым разделяются поля в каждой "куке")*

Как указал выше @Sergey Glazirin, лучше для хранения использовать localStorage, там не будет проблем с ";". А ещё лучше было бы сохранять не строки, а сами данные - свойства и их значение в виде JSON:

```
{
    objects: [
        {
            tag: 'div',
            position: 'absolute',
            width: 146,
            height: 22,
            background-color: 'rgb(131, 45, 3)',
            data-random:'true'
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var divMove = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
    divList = [],
    osX = 0,
    osY = 0,
    ae,
    Serializer = new XMLSerializer();

getRandom = (min, max) => {
  return Math.round(Math.random() *(max - min) + min);
};


function createCookie(name,value,days) {
 if (days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
 }
 else var expires = "";
 document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

btn.addEventListener('click',() => {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  divMove = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.setAttribute('data-random','true');
  div.style.width = getRandom(10,window.innerWidth/2) + 'px';
  div.style.height = getRandom(10,window.innerHeight/2) + 'px';
  div.style.top = getRandom(0,window.innerHeight) + 'px';
  div.style.left = getRandom(0,window.innerWidth) + 'px';
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + getRandom(0,255) + ',' + getRandom(0,255) + ',' + getRandom(0,255) + ')';
  var str = div.outerHTML;
  str = str.replace(/;/g, '|:')
  divList.push(str);
  createCookie('test', divList);
  drag(div);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
});

function drag(div){
  var mUp = () => {
    ae = null;
  };

  var mMove = (e) => {
    if(ae){
      ae.style.top = (e.clientY - osY) + 'px';
      ae.style.left = (e.clientX - osX) + 'px';
    }
  };
  div.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    ae = e.target;
    osX = e.offsetX;
    osY = e.offsetY;
  });

  div.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      mUp();
  });
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      mMove(e);
    });
}
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="button">Click me</input>
```

Обратите внимание на

```
str = str.replace(/;/g, '|:')
```

Тут `|:` взято как пример. При чтении вам нужно будет конвертировать обратно `|:` в `;`

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/globadaniil/qe2wphLj/19/)